# Random signal segmentation with fixed window size in Matlab

Tags: matlab, signals

Suppose a raw signal is acquired for 20 seconds with 10,000 samples, to be segmented with two-second sliding window (about 750 samples per window) to obtain all possible multiple numbers of random segments, without using Continuous Underlapping Buffer technique.

```
raw_sig = sig(:); %Raw signal in vector format%
```

The first approach was applied `buffer` technique as shown below:

```
rdm_seg = buffer(raw_sig, 750, 700);
```

The above approach produces the correct segments with 750 samples per window, but the number of segments are limited as it is based on **Continuous Overlapping Buffer** technique.

The second approach is as shown below:

```
M = 10*1000; %Number of samples in signal%
K = 750; %Number of samples to be segmented per window
n = 250; %Number of segments to be segmented

idxs=cell2mat(arrayfun(@(i)sort(randperm(M,K)),1:n,'Uniform',0)')';
```

The above approach produces all possible numbers of segments from a raw signal, but the samples are quite different from first approach, and it doesn't seem like it's supposed to be like in first approach. The signal seems corrupted in second approach see in figure below:

1. Raw signal
2. First approach result
3. Second approach result

[image]

I'm looking for segmenting raw signal with **N number of samples** for **M number of segments** which looks like second subplot figure without **continuous overlapping technique**.

Comment: Segmenting the raw signal (10,000 samples) for **N** number of random segments with 750 samples each.

Comment: It's not clear what you are looking for. Do you want to divide your samples into non-overlapping buffers? Or do you want to now use the `buffer` function?

Comment: Your first question is the one i'm looking for.

Answer (score 1):

The third parameter to the [`buffer` function](https://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/buffer.html) is the amount of overlap. Set this value to 0 to split your signal into segments that do not overlap, without skipping any values:

```
rdm_seg = buffer(raw_sig, 750, 0);
```

This is actually the same as

```
rdm_seg = buffer(raw_sig, 750);
```

because the overlap defaults to 0.

Your second approach uses `randperm`, creating a random permutation of sample indices, which is then sorted. I'm not sure what the purpose is, but it logically selects a random set of samples, not a continuous segment.

Note that it is quite simple to replicate what `buffer` does in this case, simply by reshaping the matrix. But first, we need to pad it with zeros to have an evenly-divisible length.

```
K = 750;                          % length of each segment
N = ceil(numel(raw_sig) / K);     % number of segments
M = N * K;                        % length of signal we need
rdm_seg = raw_sig;                % copy
rdm_seg(M) = 0;                   % pad with zeros
rdm_seg = reshape(rdm_seg, K, N); % reshape, each column contains K consecutive samples
```